# Busca de ceps próximos

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou implementando um sistema como um delivery online, o cliente entrará na ferramenta e colocará seu CEP, com isso o sistema deverá informar todos os restaurantes/empresas, próximas a ele.
Queria saber se alguém tem uma solução boa, para realizar essa busca. Minha ideia principal era, salvar no banco de dados todas as empresas, com seus CEPS e o raio máximo de entrega, quando o cliente fizesse a busca com seu CEP, iria trazer todas as empresas do banco e depois para cada empresa eu usaria um WebService que me retorna a distancia entre os CEPS. Porem essa solução não me parece nada eficiente.
Alguém saberia alguma forma de implementar isso?

Comment: Os correios têm base e serviço para obter CEP's, dá uma fuçada no site deles. Agora lembre-se de que um CEP é algo que abrange uma área muito grande, não um ponto - cálculos de distância baseados em CEP não serão precisos e podem dar resultados absurdos.

Comment: queres o cep mesmo ou a distancia entre eles ?

Comment: Não quero CEP, quero uma forma eficiente, de listar todos estabelecimentos próximos a um endereço.

Comment: achei uma forma de calcular a distancia somente usando o google maps, se isto ajudar de alguma forma

Comment: Então cara, isso eu tenho, o problema é, como eu vou fazer a busca no banco de dados? Pego todos os meus estabelecimentos, depois para cada registro eu calculo a distancia entre eles e vejo se aquele estabelecimento entrega naquela distancia? Isso será muito custoso

Comment: concordo com voce

Comment: Em primeiro lugar, sugiro se certificar se será mesmo muito custoso ou não. Talvez não seja, veja [esse exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11112926/520779). Agora, se for mesmo, uma possibilidade seria particionar sua área de busca. Por exemplo, divida sua região em um grid 4x4, e associe cada estabelecimento a uma ou mais posições nesse grid (i.e. se o raio de entrega faz interseção com aquele grid ou não). O cliente só estará em uma posição, de modo que o número de estabelecimentos em potencial diminui bastante. Se este número ainda for grande, subdivida cada região em outro grid 4x4, etc.

Comment: Acho que o  mgibsonbr, me disse pode ser a solução ideal, agora eu só preciso chamar o webservice uma vez, para transformar o cep em lat e lng e depois utilizo aquela query. Ainda não testei mas faz todo sentido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa desenvolver um banco de dados que contenham as latitudes e longitudes de cada uma das empresas que você deseja exibir nos resultados. Quando o usuário informar seu endereço você deverá integrar com algum serviço de geolocalização (google maps, por exemplo) e encontrar a latitude e longitude do endereço do usuário. Baseado nesses dois pontos é fácil calcular.

Siga esse exemplo do próprio Google:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Answer (score 3):

Usando as funçaoes GEOIP de PHP, vc pode ter "mas o menos" uma idea da posiçao (GPS) da pessao. No caso de um aplicativo tipo Android o iPhone e mas facil.

Depois disso, na sua tabela de dados com restaurant, lojas.. vc precisa indicar para cada um, a posiçao. Tambem com GPS.

Depois disso, vai precisa calcular a distanca entre os dois (o "cliente" e a "loja").
Aqui um pequeno codigo para calculara a distanca:
http://www.phpsources.org/scripts459-PHP.htm

Cuidadao tem um monte que nao usam o tamaho da terra/ Eles dao uma distança com precisao fraca, o que, no caso de v, nao seria suficiente.